# Multiple base numbers parser

Tags: parsing, haskell, integer, number-systems, parsec

This code is a Parser that parses numbers according to `R5RS`.

- #b1001 - binary
- #o2127 - octal
- #h02d  - hexadecimal
- #d1231 - decimal
- 3923 - decimal

It is working at the moment, the only problem is the `parseNumberBase`. I am really new to haskell, but it does not look very good to me.

- How could I improve it? (readability wise)
- It would also be nice to see a more "idiomatic" approach

---

```
import Data.Char (digitToInt)
import Numeric (readInt, readOct, readHex)
import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe, fromJust)

parseNumber :: Parser LispVal
parseNumber = parseNumberBase 'd'
          <|> do char '#'
                 base <- oneOf "bdoh"
                 parseNumberBase base

-- | Parses a number at a specific base
parseNumberBase :: Char -> Parser LispVal
parseNumberBase 'b' =
    do digits <- many1 (oneOf "01")
       return $ (Number . fromJust . readBinary) digits
parseNumberBase 'o' =
    do digits <- many1 octDigit
       return $ Number (fst (readOct digits !! 0))
parseNumberBase 'd' =
    do digits <- many1 digit
       return $ (Number . read) digits
parseNumberBase 'h' =
    do digits <- many1 hexDigit
       return $ Number (fst (readHex digits !! 0))
parseNumberBase _ =
    error "Wrong number base"

readBinary :: String -> Maybe Integer
readBinary =
    fmap fst . listToMaybe . readInt 2 (`elem` "01") digitToInt
```

Comment: You didn't include all code. What's `Parser`?

Answer (score 2):

```
do
   digits <- someParser
   return $ someFunction digits
```

is just

```
someFunction <$> someParser
```

We can make `parseNumberBase` a lot shorter with that information:

```
-- | Parses a number at a specific base
parseNumberBase :: Char -> Parser LispVal
parseNumberBase 'b' = Number . fromJust . readBinary <$> many1 (oneOf "01")
parseNumberBase 'o' = Number . fst . head . readOct  <$> many1 octDigit     -- see below
parseNumberBase 'd' = Number . read                  <$> many1 digit
parseNumberBase 'h' = Number . fst . head . readHex  <$> many1 hexDigit     -- see below
parseNumberBase _   = error "Wrong number base"
```

`readFunc digits !! 0` is `head (readFunc digits)`, so we were able to get rid of `!!` too.

That being said, `parseNumberBase` has a lot of responsibility. Split it into multiple parsers, and it's suddenly a lot easier to grasp:

```
parseBinary :: Parser LispVal
parseBinary = Number . fromJust . readBinary <$> many1 (oneOf "01")

parseDecimal :: Parser LispVal
parseDecimal = Number . read <$> many1 digit

parseHexadecimal :: Parser LispVal
parseHexadecimal = Number . fst . head . readHex <$> many1 hexDigit

parseOct :: Parser LispVal
parseOct = Number . fst . head . readOct  <$> many1 octDigit
```

We can now test all those functions in isolation. We can now write `parseNumberBase` as another parser:

```
parseNumber :: Parser LispVal
parseNumber = parseDecimal <|> char '#' *> parseNumberBase

parseNumberBase :: Parser LispVal
parseNumberBase =  char 'h' *> parseHexadecimal 
               <|> char 'd' *> parseDecimal 
               <|> char 'o' *> parseOct
               <|> char 'b' *> parseBinary
```